# How to apply custom function with many parameters in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function

```
import math
def f(k,a,x):
    return (1/(1+math.exp(-k*x))^a)
```

And the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': list(range(1,100))})
```

How can I apply the above `function` on the `x` column of the `df` for lets say `k=1` and `a=2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your function:

```
def f(k,a,x):
    return (1/(1+math.exp(-k*x))**a)

df['out'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: f(k=1, a=2, x=x))
```

But better vectorize with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

def f_vectorized(k, a, x):
    return (1/(1+np.exp(-k*x))**a)

df['out'] = f_vectorized(k=1, a=2, x=df['x'])
```

Output:

```
     x       out
0    1  0.534447
1    2  0.775803
2    3  0.907397
3    4  0.964351
4    5  0.986659
..  ..       ...
94  95  1.000000
95  96  1.000000
96  97  1.000000
97  98  1.000000
98  99  1.000000

[99 rows x 2 columns]
```